# check checkbox with the same value and then show div

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I have a code where if you check checkbox with the same value other checkboxes with that value also checks, but I want that when it is checked also show div and if it's unchecked hide.

I tried this, but that don't work. Any help is welcome. Thank you!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
        if($('input[value="' + this.value + '"]:checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked)) {
    $(".div1").show();
} else { 
    $(".div1").hide();
}
    });
});
```

```css
.div1 {
display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" value="one">1
  <input type="checkbox" value="two">2 
</div>
<div class="div1">
  <p>This is text</p>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" value="one">1
  <input type="checkbox" value="two">2 
</div>
<div class="div1">
  <p>This is another text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You have to use `change` event to get if checkbox is well cheked or not. `click` event is called too early.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
  $('input[value="' + this.value + '"]:checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked)
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {//change if condition
      $(".div1").show();
    } else {
      $(".div1").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.div1 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" value="one">1
  <input type="checkbox" value="two">2
</div>
<div class="div1">
  <p>This is text</p>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" value="one">1
  <input type="checkbox" value="two">2
</div>
<div class="div1">
  <p>This is another text</p>
</div>
```

1. Change if condition because your condition `$('input[value="' + this.value + '"]:checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked)` is not returning Boolean value it is setting the checkbox to `checked` or `unchecked`
2. I would suggest to use `change` instead of `click`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {//suggest to use change
  $('input[value="' + this.value + '"]:checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked)
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {//change if condition
      $(".div1").show();
    } else {
      $(".div1").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.div1 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" value="one">1
  <input type="checkbox" value="two">2
</div>
<div class="div1">
  <p>This is text</p>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" value="one">1
  <input type="checkbox" value="two">2
</div>
<div class="div1">
  <p>This is another text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: A description of the problem always helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You main issue is that you're putting a jQuery object in an `if` condition. This will always equate to `true`, hence the `show()` is always called on the `.div1` element.

To fix this, set the `prop()` separately, then use `toggle()` to show or hide the div based on the `checked` property of the checkbox.

Also note that when dealing with checkboxes and radio buttons you should use the `change` event for accessibility reasons. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
    $('input[value="' + this.value + '"]:checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
    $(".div1").toggle(this.checked);
  });
});
```

```css
.div1 { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" value="one">1
  <input type="checkbox" value="two">2
</div>
<div class="div1">
  <p>This is text</p>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" value="one">1
  <input type="checkbox" value="two">2
</div>
<div class="div1">
  <p>This is another text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could simply test:

```
if(this.checked) {
    $(".div1").show();
} else { 
    $(".div1").hide();
}
```

I updated your snippet, see:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
        if(this.checked) {
          $(".div1").show();
        } else { 
            $(".div1").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.div1 {
display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" value="one">1
  <input type="checkbox" value="two">2 
</div>
<div class="div1">
  <p>This is text</p>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" value="one">1
  <input type="checkbox" value="two">2 
</div>
<div class="div1">
  <p>This is another text</p>
</div>
```

I hope it helps you, bye